# AudioVideoPlayback doesn`t work at all. How to fix it?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and testing Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback library function.(using VS2019)
VS said there are no error, but nothing happened when I compiled it.

I have tested below code line by line. and found that Init() function does not work at all. I have tested other paths such as

@"C:\Users\name\Videos\sample.mp4"

"C:\Users\name\Videos\sample.mp4"

"C:\Users\name\Videos\sample.mp4"

but all of them does not work at all too.
How to fix the code and why it did`t work properly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
using System.IO;

namespace hello
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init();
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            Video v = Video.FromFile(@"C:\Users\name\Videos\sample.mp4");
            v.Owner = this;
            v.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
            v.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

This might be too simple question, but cannot gain any solution from other answers in this site.

Comment: what happens call init after the form has been shown, eg on a button click

Comment: Do you have the necessary audio and video codecs for this media file installed on your system? (MP4 is just a container format. Use some media player not relying on system-installed codecs, such as VLC, to inspect the media file in question to find out the audio and video codec)

Comment: @BugFinder really nothing  happens. VS is running but any windows or alert  won`t show up. But if I disable init function(//init();), then Foam1 window showed up.

Comment: @elgonzo Doesn`t Visual studio contains 'Window media player' as default and WMP have all codecs for MP4?

Comment: I guess, you shouldn't start the video while the constructor has not finished. Try starting it from Form_Loaded event or something similar.

Comment: @hello_mother you cant have tried what I suggested, as the form would have shown as it wouldnt have tried to run the video until the button click.. errors in winform constructors tend to get eaten

Comment: I am also suspicious if the v.Play method should run on the UI thread? But that's just a guess.

Comment: @Fildor I have tested it by using Form1_Load(), Form1_Activated() events but neither them aren`t work at all too.

Comment: @Fildor you are right. v.Play thread doesn`t exist in thread window

Comment: Which version of the assembly and which .Net version are you using? Try to compile your project with .Net 2 and see what happens (you may need to remove the break on LoaderLock Exceptions in VS).

Comment: "_Visual studio contains 'Window media player'_" Why should Visual Studio contain the Windows Media Player? It is called "Windows Media Player" and not "Visual Studio Media Player" for a reason... "_WMP have all codecs for MP4?_" Don't know; I don't use WMP (personally, i use MPC-HC and the codecs from the "LAV Filters" package...)